# Nextgen wordpress plugin: url to gallery tag

Tags: wordpress, tags

I developed a plugin that appear people information and in the end of this I put some pictures. Well, I want to put one link to gallery tag, but I don't know how can I do it

For the gallery I use this function: nggShowRelatedGallery($tag, 10); and I want to use $tag var in the link. For example, if I put: http://www.web.com/gallery/tag/cars I would like that appear all photos of "cars" tag.

Anybody can help me?

Thanks U :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [rewrite Api](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API).
It will get you far.